# Why some user functions don't get recognised by bash with sudo?

Tags: command-line, bash

**Initial conditions :**
I have defined a function and export it:

```
myfunction () { echo OK ; }
export -f myfunction
```

I have a simple bash file :
test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
myfunction
```

**Test OK with the current user :**
If I run :

```
bash test.sh
```

It works :)

**Does not work with sudo :**
But if I run in sudo :

```
sudo bash test.sh
```

I have the error :

```
test.sh: ligne2: myfunction : commande introuvable
```

which means

```
test.sh: line2: myfunction : command not found
```

**Question**

Why my function does not work in sudo ?
How it can work in sudo ?

Thank you very much  :)

Comment: Does it use your user files? If so, it requires the full path (because otherwise it defaults to `/root` not `/home/username`. So instead of referring to `Pictures`, refer to `/home/username/Pictures`.

Comment: Posting your script would be helpful...

Comment: This question was already asked on Superuser (https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables), StackOverflow, twice (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903247/preserve-sudo-environment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633461/how-to-keep-environment-variables-when-using-sudo), and Unix, 3 times. These are 6 of the first 7 results on Google when I search for `sudo preserve environment variables`.

Comment: In fact, this seems to be the only relevant SE site this question wasn't asked on (properly). It was even (sort of) asked on ServerFault.

Answer (score 6):

For security reasons `sudo` throws away shell functions and most environment variables before running its child process.

You need to include the definition of `myfunction` into `test.sh`.

Comment: Is there any other way to share function or alias with `sudo` ? In my real situation, I have only 1 function `myfunction` and about 50 script `test.sh`

Comment: Yes @sangorys, there is a switch you can use. I forget what it is at the moment, but when I remember (read: search for it), I will post it.